# how to change data with combobox in laravel?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5.8

I want to update the combobox, but when i run the program the error appears. the error said

> Undefined variable: jenis (View: D:\laravel\makanan\resources\views\edit_upload.blade.php)

what is the solution and what sintax to use ?

this is sintax in the controller:

```
 public function prosesedit($id, Request $request)
    {
        $makan = Gambar::find($id);
        $nama_file = $makan->file;
        $jenis = JenisMkn::select('id_jenis','jenis_makanan')->get();

        if($request->hasfile('file'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
            $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);
        }

        $makan->update([
            'file'=>$nama_file,
            'nama_makanan'=>$request->makan,
            'kode_makanan'=>$request->jenis,
            'paket'=>implode(',',$request->paket),
            'pembayaran'=>$request->transaksi,
        ]);
        return redirect(route('makan'));
```

and this is html

```
<div class="form-group">
                   <b>Jenis Makanan</b>
                   <br/>
                   <select name="jenis" id="" class="form control input-sm">
                       @foreach ($jenis as $j)
                           <option value="{{$j->id_jenis}}">{{$j->jenis_makanan}}</option>
                       @endforeach
                   </select>
               </div>
```

Comment: can you give me the controller with that function where you return this blade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the return of controller like this:

```
return redirect(route('makan'))->with('jenis', $jenis);
```

Comment: `return redirect(route('makan'));` itu returnnya ke edit_upload.blade.php ?

Comment: nah di func yg return ke edit_upload.blade.php dikasih `with('jenis', $jenis)` karena disitu katanya dia gak bisa nemuin variabel jenis

Comment: ooohh, iya saya taruh di return edit_upload.blade.php baru berhasil, makasih banyak ya